# Bringing another process to front in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application. Inside the application during a button click I create a new process to open a new application like below code from my view model.

```
var process = Process.Start(binaryLocation
                                  + @"\TestApp.exe", powDBop + " " + mDBop);

processID = process.Id;
```

It works fine. Now the problem is if user clicks on the button again, I check whether the process is alive, and if it is alive **I need to bring the Window of that application to the front**.

For that I tried below code. But it is failing.

```
var winHandle = Process.GetProcessById(process.Id).MainWindowHandle;
HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(winHandle);
var window = hwndSource.RootVisual as Window;
window.BringIntoView();
window.Activate();
```

**hwndSource** is not being set and remains null.

I even tried with below code and still window returns null.

```
var winHandle = Process.GetProcessById(process.Id).MainWindowHandle;
Window window = (Window) HwndSource.FromHwnd(winHandle).RootVisual;
```

Anyone?

Comment: Does Topmost = true works?

Comment: @nkoniishvt : Nop. The window instance is not being created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it with the following code

```
var process = Process.Start(binaryLocation
                                  + @"\TestApp.exe", powDBop + " " + mDBop);

  SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: Working fine. But I have a doubt. Why use unmanaged code **[DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);**

Is it possible to achieve without this??

Comment: I doubt it is possible without dllimport. However, you could use some kind of inter procese comunication in order to send message to the new process. The new process can then react to the message by bringing the window to foreground

Comment: I think hWnd targeting Window that doesn't belong to WPF so it will be always null.It should be in the same app domain

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways.